# Simple cocoapods install bug with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, cocoapods

This seems like a super simple pod install, yet I'm getting this strange error. Just don't see what's wrong here.

Podfile

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'iLook-990' do
 use_frameworks!

 pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 1.0.0'

end
```

Error message:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `OAuthSwift (~> 1.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

  None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:      `OAuthSwift (~> 1.0.0)`.

  You have either:

  - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
  - mistyped the name or version.
  - not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that's the exact same text from the Podfile, you need to remove the # from the first line

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'iLook-990' do
 use_frameworks!

 pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 1.0.0'

end
```